# How to create textview headers like those found in Android People App

Tags: android, textview

I am new to android development and am trying to create an activity with header controls similar to those found in the Add Contact activity found within the Android People app.  For example, I want to create headers that look like the:

Contact Type
Phone
Email

that fill the width, have a left indent, have the 3D lines found above and below and provide the ability to include a vertical separator line on the right with a bottom to the right of the vertical line.

I've been looking for samples but have come up empty handed.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you please add screenshot...

Comment: Believe me 1 snap = 1000 words!!

Comment: He is asking this                     style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"  attribute I guess !